# Why this Join-Update query update all value?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I made some mistake and all values of a column are updated.

I did this in SQL Server 2008 R2.

I should have run some query like this:

```
UPDATE TABLE_A
SET FEEL = 'HAPPY'
FROM TABLE_A A 
INNER JOIN TABLE_B B ON A.SN = B.SN
WHERE B.WEATHER = 'SUNNY';
```

However, I made a mistake and ran this:

```
UPDATE TABLE_A
SET FEEL = 'HAPPY'
FROM TABLE_C A 
INNER JOIN TABLE_B B ON A.SN = B.SN
WHERE B.WEATHER = 'SUNNY';
```

and even `TABLE_C` has column of `[SN]`.

I expected that this query update FEEL of TABLE_A as 'HAPPY' where `WEATHER` of `TABLE_B` is 'SUNNY' with inner join between two tables, but every value of column `FEEL` is updated to 'HAPPY'.

What means `Update A set ~ from c` in SQL Server and when it should be used? And why "inner-join" updates all values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query:

```
UPDATE TABLE_A
     SET FEEL = 'HAPPY'
     FROM TABLE_C A INNER JOIN
          TABLE_B B
          ON A.SN = B.SN
    WHERE B.WEATHER = 'SUNNY';
```

is saying to update all rows in `TABLE_A` that match the conditions in the `ON` and `WHERE` clauses.  But, none of those conditions involve `TABLE_A`.  So, nothing is being filtered.  Actually, what you are doing is equivalent to:

```
UPDATE AA
     SET FEEL = 'HAPPY'
     FROM TABLE AA CROSS JOIN
          TABLE_C A INNER JOIN
          TABLE_B B
          ON A.SN = B.SN
    WHERE B.WEATHER = 'SUNNY';
```

This is a bit of weirdness in the `UPDATE`.

When you do:

```
UPDATE TABLE_A
    SET FEEL = 'HAPPY'
    FROM TABLE_A A INNER JOIN
         TABLE_B B
         ON A.SN = B.SN
     WHERE B.WEATHER = 'SUNNY';
```

SQL Server makes an exception to the rule that an alias *always* replaces the table reference.  It still allows `TABLE_A` in the `UPDATE` to refer to `A`.  So, there is no `CROSS JOIN`.

Personally, I consider this broken-ness, because a table alias should always replace the table reference.  The developers at Microsoft think otherwise.  And there is no standard that guides this syntax.

If you have a `FROM` clause, I recommend that *always* use table aliases.

```
UPDATE A
    SET FEEL = 'HAPPY'
    FROM TABLE_A A INNER JOIN
         TABLE_B B
         ON A.SN = B.SN
     WHERE B.WEATHER = 'SUNNY';
```

Comment: Yes, I definitely *always* use a table alias after `UPDATE`. Otherwise things can get "dangerous". ;-)

Comment: Thank you for kind answer. Undoubtedly helpful!